# How do I search for partial accented keyword in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following elasticsearch settings:

```
"settings": {
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "analyzer_keyword":{
                 "tokenizer":"keyword",
                 "filter":["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
              }
           }
        }
     }
}
```

The above works fine for the following keywords:

- Beyoncé
- Céline Dion

The above data is stored in elasticsearch as `beyonce` and `celine dion` respectively.

I can search for `Celine` or `Celine Dion` without the accent and I get the same results. However, the moment I search for `Céline`, I don't get any results. How can I configure elasticsearch to search for partial keywords with the accent?

The query body looks like:

```
{
   "track_scores": true,
   "query": {
       "bool": {
           "must": [
               {
                   "multi_match": {
                       "fields": ["name"],
                       "type": "phrase",
                       "query": "Céline"
                   }

               }

           ]
       }
   }
}
```

and the mapping is

```
"mappings" : {
  "artist" : {
    "properties" : {
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "fields" : {
          "orig" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "simple" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "analyzer" : "analyzer_keyword"
          }
        },
      }
```

Comment: What does your query look like? What about the mapping for the field you are search?

Comment: @eemp Query body updated in question

Comment: You didn't provide the mapping, as asked.

Comment: And what does "partial" keywords mean? You search for "Céline". That's not partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this mapping and then go from there:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "analyzer_keyword": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string", 
          "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I created a new analyzer and set the tokenizer to whitespace, this one works well.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the same analyzer is getting used at query time.  Here are some possible reasons why that might not be happening:

- you specify a separate analyzer at query time on purpose that is not performing similar analysis
- you are using a `term` or `terms` query for which no analyzer is applied (See [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) and the section title "Why doesn’t the term query match my document?")
- you are using a `query_string` query (E.g. see [Simple Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html)) - I have found that if you specify multiple fields with different analyzers and so I have needed to separate the fields into separate queries and specify the analyzer parameter (working with version 2.0)